# Which directory to install Wget

Tags: windows-10, wget

I have installed Wget. But I'm just not sure where I need to put the wget.exe file. Because I already have searched where to put wget.exe. But didn't find where the best place is to put it. Do I need to put the wget.exe in the `Program Files` folder or the `System32` folder? Because I don't know if it is safe to put exe files in the `System32`. Or do I need to put the wget.exe file somewhere else to let it work.

Comment: If [this](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-wget-in-windows-10/) is what your talking about then you can put it in any location you want.

Comment: That actually doesn't sound like you've _installed_ wget, rather that you've downloaded it from somewhere. As @Ramhound sez you can put it anywhere you want, but for convenience you should put it in a location that's in your %PATH%. If you're following Ramhound's link the installer will put it in Program Files (x86), which is both safe and convenient, unless you specify another path.

Comment: Ever since Windows 95, I have had my own folder called `c:\utils` which is on my `PATH`, and I put 3rd party command-line utilities, (curl, wget, etc) and some other apps, in that folder. I also have a folder called `c:\batch` which is also on my `PATH`.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can I just create a new `PATH` in my system? And choose a directory I want?

Comment: You can add a folder to the PATH system variable, plenty of guides to doing that on the web this is just one example here https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!